# Wordpress Plugin Using Permalinks

Tags: php, url-rewriting, wordpress

So i created a plugin that is basically a gallery that you choose options as you go.

First choose Brand
Then Color
Then Style

At each step i am passing the variables via $_GET

So once you have chosen your brand and continue the next page URL is `cabinets/?brand=1`

Then after you choose your color it is `cabinets/?brand=1&color=2`

i have written a rewrite for this that is supposed to make pretty urls but all it is doing is showing the home page.

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array','cabinets_rewrite_rules_array');
function cabinets_rewrite_rules_array($rules){

    $cabinets_slug = 'cabinets';
    $my_cab_rules[$cabinets_slug.'/?$'] = $cabinets_slug."/?brand=$matches[1]";
    $my_cab_rules[$cabinets_slug.'/(.+?)/?$'] = $cabinets_slug."/?brand=$matches[1]&color=$matches[2]"; 
    $my_cab_rules[$cabinets_slug.'/(.+?)/(.+?)/?$'] = $cabinets_slug."/?brand=$matches[1]&color=$matches[2]&style=$matches[3]"; 

    return $my_cab_rules + $rules;

}
```

i have tried many things even as much as updating the htaccess file but i dont want to have to do that since this is a plugin.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding your new variables to the list of query vars.

```
function prfx_add_query_vars($aVars) {
    global $wp_query;

    $aVars[] = "brand";
    $aVars[] = "color";
    $aVars[] = "style";

    return $aVars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'prfx_add_query_vars');
```

Comment: What would that do for me?